# passing 2d array to a different page

Tags: php, arrays

hi 
this is pushan
I am using $_SESSION['name']='the 2d array name', to assign a dynamically created 2d array to a session variable in php.when I am accessing the session variable in the other page anfd printing the values only the values of the last row of the 2d array is getting printed . the rest is all blank.Please help me I am under tremendous pressure.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you assign only a string to the session variable. But you have to assign the array itself:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = array(...);
// or a reference of the array
$_SESSION['name'] = $array2;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to save the array to the session as a string, then [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to recover it later.

Page 1:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = serialize($arrayName);
```

Page 2:

```
$arrayName = unserialize($_SESSION['name']);
var_dump($arrayName);
```

Comment: You don't need to serialize data before storing them into a session variable.

Comment: Fair point ... I'd just assumed the problem was with the array being added to the session, but it's more likely to be the session itself ...